# Bootstrap tooltip not showing right when aligned to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the tooltip I have now and it works fine:

[image]

But what I do really need is to align it to the right. So, when I `.pull-right` it looks like this:

[image]

This is may html:

```
<div class="wrapper">Login
    <span rel="tooltip" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-trigger="hover" 
    data-placement="right" 
    data-html="true"
    data-title="Aenean nibh neque, mattis id diam non, placerat imperdiet urna.">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

and this is the tooltip call: `$('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull the wrapper, not the tooltip.

```
<div class="wrapper pull-right">Login
    <span rel="tooltip" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-trigger="hover" 
    data-placement="right" 
    data-html="true"
    data-title="Aenean nibh neque, mattis id diam non, placerat imperdiet urna.">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```